# SQL - MariaDB JOIN Quesiton

Tags: mysql

[image]

[image]

[image]

Hi all, I'm working on some simple queries(I'm a noob) and thought I'd stop by here to get some educated advice. I posted a link to the two tables I made for Parents and Players on a team.

Im trying to write a query that returns students that have both parents enrolled into the system. So it should display the student and both parents as well. I can get the INNER JOIN for each player and parent but can't seem to get it down to parent per student > 1 or = 2.

I've tried using the Distinct clause but cant get that to work either. Any help would be great thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT()` to get both parents in the result. And you need `GROUP BY pl_id` to get a row for each player.

```
SELECT pl.pl_fname, pl.pl_lname, pl.pl_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(pa.pa_fname, ' ', pa.pa_lname, ', ', pa.pa_id, ' ', pa.pa_address SEPARATOR '; ') AS parents
FROM Player AS pl
JOIN Parent AS pa ON pl.pl_lname = pa.pl_lname
GROUP BY pl.pl_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Or if you want each parent in separate rows, join with a query that counts the number of parents.

```
SELECT pl.pl_fname, pl.pl_lname, pl.pl_id, pa.pa_fname, pa.pa_lname, pa.pa_id, pa.pa_address 
FROM Player AS pl
JOIN Parent AS pa ON pl.pl_lname = pa.pl_lname
JOIN (SELECT pa_lname FROM parent GROUP BY pa_lname HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) AS pa1
    ON pl.pl_lname = pa1.pa_lname
```